# Insert Value below merged column cells

Tags: c#, excel, oledbcommand

I would like to insert a Value into Points where the Person = ‘John’ the column heading is ‘Oct-14’

The top cell that contains ‘Oct-14’ is a merger of two cells and below are single cells containing ‘Points’ and ‘Days’.

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Update [Sheet1$] "+
    "set [Points] = ‘Value ’ where [Person]='John'  AND  ? = ‘Oct-14’ ", cn);
```

```
          
---------------------------------------------------------      
|                |   Oct-14          |      Nov-14      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|Person          |   Points |  Days  |  Points |  Days  |   
---------------------------------------------------------
|John            |  'Value' |        |          |       |
---------------------------------------------------------
|Jodie           |          |        |          |       |
---------------------------------------------------------
|Alex            |          |        |          |       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: why not split your input value to match those 2 columns?

Comment: Lets say 'Oct-14' is in cell K1 and below Points is in K2 and Days is in  L1   Where ever John is I would like to add his Value in Points  for the month 'Oct-14'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it will enter the data into the first cell when you have merged cells. Move "Person" to the first row and add HDR=YES;.

```
  OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Update [Sheet1$] "+
        "set [Oct-14] = ‘Value ’ where [Person]='John', cn);
```

For the date if there are issues just using Oct-14 try converting it to a OLE Automation date.

```
      var DateToCheck = (int) DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("01/11/2014"),
      new CultureInfo("en-GB")).ToOADate();
```